# Formatting of select choices is wrong - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django-views, django-ajax-selects

My second select dropdown is populating with each letter of the data I'm returning from my server and not each item itself.

[image]

Here's my JQuery;

```
var selected_table = $("#id_TableName option:selected").text();
            $.get('/historicaldata/input_parameters/', { selected_table : selected_table }, function(data){
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    for (var key in data[i]) {
                        $('<option />', {
                            value: key,
                            text: data[i][key]
                        }).appendTo("#id_ColumnName");
                    }
                }
            });
```

My data looks like this when it is returned from my view after the GET request;

```
{'option1': ['option1'], 'option2': ['option2'], 'option3': ['option3']}
```

Although I've tried a few similar formats and the outcome is the same so I think the fault is with the JQuery.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1. It looks to me as though your server isn't returning the correct `Content-Type` header with the reply, so jQuery doesn't realize it's JSON and auto-deserialize it for you. So your loop loops through the characters of the string.

   You can force the matter by adding a call to [`jQuery.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) (`$.parseJSON` if you use the `$` shortcut):

   ```
   data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
   ```

   ...as the first line of the success handler (shown in context below), but the better option would be to correct the `Content-Type` the server is sending back. The content type the server should be sending back is `application/json`.
2. Your code is expecting to get back an array, but from the

   ```
   {'option1': ['option1'], 'option2': ['option2'], 'option3': ['option3']}
   ```

   ...you quoted, you're not sending back an array, you're sending back something *like* a JSON object (but with invalid quotes, see #3 below). Once you fix #3 below, then you can loop through the names of the properties using `for (var propName in data)` (`propName` will be `"option1"`, `"option2"`, etc., **in no guaranteed order**). If you need a specific order, change your server-side output to output an array instead:

   ```
   ["option1", "option2", "option3"]
   ```

   ...and then stick with your existing loop.
3. The JSON you're sending back is invalid. JSON requires property names and strings to be in *double* quotes (`"`), not single quotes (`'`). So:

   ```
   {"option1": ["option1"], "option2": ["option2"], "option3": ["option3"]}
   ```

   ...or again, use an array:

   ```
   ["option1", "option2", "option3"]
   ```

Here's the `parseJSON` call in context, but again, it would be better if the server sent back the correct `Content-Type`, and you'll also have to update how you access the data:

```
var selected_table = $("#id_TableName option:selected").text();
$.get('/historicaldata/input_parameters/', {
    selected_table: selected_table
}, function(data) {
    data = $.parseJSON(data);     // <====== Added
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (var key in data[i]) {
            $('<option />', {
                value: key,
                text: data[i][key]
            }).appendTo("#id_ColumnName");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @MarkCorrigan: Dunno, what server-side technology are you using? Whatever it is, search for "setting content type" or "setting headers" (as `Content-Type` is a standard header). In PHP, for instance, it would be `header("Content-Type: application/json");` In ASP.Net using C#, it would be `Response.SetContentType("application/json");`

Comment: also gettng an error in firefox debugger SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' are you aware of what this refers to?

Comment: @MarkCorrigan: Probably #3 above. I added that late, when I realized you were using single quotes rather than doubles. (My content type examples in the comment above were also wrong thanks to a typo [been a long day already, it's only 3pm!], hit refresh to make sure you're seeing `application/json` there.)

Comment: `data = $.parseJSON(data);     // <====== Added` are you serious? `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {` and then `parseJSON` ?

Comment: @webdeveloper: Thanks, I pasted it in the wrong place! Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is your example (you getting string):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5JNSz/

If you fix your string, so it become correct `json` and use `JSON.parse()` OR jquery `$.parseJSON`:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dv9Ly/

Note: object doesn't have `length` property.

Something like this should work, if you fix content type issue:

```
for (var key in data) {
    $('<option />', {
        value: key,
        text: data[key][0]
    }).appendTo("#id_ColumnName");
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Vm7jQ/